# CouchDB view with include_docs=true yields doc: null

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb

I have 2 distinct data types in the same couchdb database, `message` and `user`. They look like follows:

```
// message
{
   "_id": "test__032142f981b1bddd00bb9a0161688480",
   "_rev": "8-d1b19caabac334c4b9e9eb1f0b0b8986",
   "created": "2011-12-27T23:48:17.940699Z",
   "text": "Omnis quam nesciunt dolor quaerat.",
   "author_id": "test__d3f62f343144dfef8fd112946da9c1b3",
   "type": "message",
   "subject": "Some text"
   "recipients": [
        "user id 1",
        "user id 2",
   ]
}

//user
{
   "_id": "test__d3f62f343144dfef8fd112946da9c1b3",
   "_rev": "12-88206492cc5274248aa5a64ff6a49b9a",
   "type": "user",
   "profile": {
       "callname": "User name",
       "fullname": "User name",
       "profile_text": "Blah blah",
       "urls": [
           {
               "url": "http://www.example.org",
               "description": "CV, Blog, Pictures, Research, Links",
               "label": "Homepage"
           }
       ],
       "profile_image_url": "http://localhost:5000/static/img/profiles/2e38f9fdd9e458eb4db0e7bb3b8e9576.jpg"
   },
   "registration_date": "2014-08-14T20:07:28Z",
   "verified": "none",
   "preferences": {
       "lang": "en"
   },
   "last_login": "2014-08-14T20:07:28Z",
   "email": "user@example.org"
}
```

Out of reasons, inlining is not a possibility in this case. What I want now is to get a list of all messages with the author object included (Like SQL `SELECT * FROM messages JOIN users on message.author_id = message.id`).

I read this two articles:

- http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins
- http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Linked_documents

So I wanted to use `include_docs=true` and then a `list` to format it nicely. My `messages` map function:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'message') {
        emit(doc._id, {_id: doc.author_id, entity: doc});
    }
}
```

I call this using the URL `http://localhost:5984/dedri/_design/dedri/_view/messages?include_docs=true`. But I get this, with `doc: null`:

```
{
    "total_rows": 34,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "test__032142f981b1bddd00bb9a0161688480",
            "key": "test__032142f981b1bddd00bb9a0161688480",
            "value": {
                "_id": "test__d3f62f343144dfef8fd112946da9c1b3",
                "entity": {
                    "_id": "test__032142f981b1bddd00bb9a0161688480",
                    "_rev": "8-d1b19caabac334c4b9e9eb1f0b0b8986",
                    "created": "2011-12-27T23:48:17.940699Z",
                    "text": "Omnis quam nesciunt dolor quaerat.",
                    "version": "0.1",
                    "author_id": "test__d3f62f343144dfef8fd112946da9c1b3",
                    "type": "message",
                    "subject": "Some text"
                }
            },
            "doc": null
        },
        ...
```

I don't know what to do anymore. There is no editing or deleting done in the map function. Is this a problem of mine or a bug?

Comment: As I found out now, everything I did here was correct. The bug was in our test data generation code, which did not create matching user ids properly. So, I will close the question as it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your map js to a simpler form for debugging, e.g.

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'message') {
        // emit(doc._id, {_id: doc.author_id, entity: doc});
        emit(doc._id, { '_id': doc.author_id });
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly the same comes out, just without the entity part.

Comment: for debugging purposes, maybe you can try calling the views from `curl` with the `include_docs` param